# (iOS-Servlet) Converting http synchronous to sockets

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, sockets, servlets

I have an iOS program. I have a servlet java program on the server side. I am sending an image from the iOS app to the servlet and servlet received it.

This is programmed in http communication currently, using `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` on the iOS front.

I want to convert this program to work in socket communication. The same image data that I'm sending through synchronous http request will have to be changed to send via socket connection and Servlet program will have to be converted to listen & receive for it using socket code.

Can someone please redirect to the right tutorials and suggest me the approach please?

Answer (score 0):

You can not control this in your code.  The connection is handled by the servlet container, not the Servlet.  If you are not using HTTP there is really no point in using Servlets.  You would probably need to set this up to run as a stand alone service.